# Jenkinsfile to start & stop docker containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

Docker application runs well but would like to manage docker containers using Jenkins with regards to starting and stopping of docker containers in a pipeline.

Would like to seek help with regards to crafting the Jenkinsfile from scratch. Upon building the docker image using the `$ docker build -t <imagename> .` and running the application `$ docker run -p 8501:8501 <imagename>`, the application can be accessed under **localhost:8501**.

The git repository is available under this link: https://github.com/nichostst/reliability.git and the `Dockerfile` is as shown below:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

LABEL maintainer = "Nicholas ST <nichostst@gmail.com>"
LABEL version = "0.1"

WORKDIR /reliability

COPY . /reliability

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "src/main.py"]
```

Comment: how is this related to git?

Comment: @DaemonPainter, apologies have removed the tag

Comment: no need to apologize

Comment: What does your current Jenkins pipeline code look like?  What problem are you having with it?  Are the contents of the Docker image important to the question?

Answer (score 0):

in regards to [jenkinsfile pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label) you have many ways using docker in a pipeline.

you did not specify whether you just want to build a docker image or to use a docker runtime (executing your project code within a container).

i will assume that you seek the latter. meaning, running your code within a container.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      filename 'Dockerfile'
      dir '.'
      args ''
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('prep') {
      steps {
        echo 'preparing...'
        sh '''
        # run command within the container
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and you can always use `sh` to run `docker` native commands